# Admob works doesn't gives me money

Tags: android, admob, ads

I added admob to my android app, the banners are sometimes shown sometimes are not but that is okey. The thing that is weird for me is that when I logging to admob.com page and I check my account I see that the field for requests is increasing and in the moment is 30, the eCPM is 0$ and the RPM is 0$, also the fill rate field is something like 5%.

```
Requests       30
eCPM           0$
Fill Rate      5%
RPM            0$
```

I have many questions, but my main question is why I do not get any money ?

I guess I didn't done something in my code so I do not earn money...
I do not know what I am missing. I take the publisher ID from the admob, and I putted in the code to the right place, and obviously it works cause the requests are increasing. But why I do not get any money ? Did I need to do something else ? some other permission or something ?

I really do not have experience with admob, maybe this is not the place to ask questions but still I asked cause I think the problem is in my code , I think that I am missing something.

NOTE:
my app is not published in the market, is that the problem ? Is it requirement app to be published to the marked so the admob can works ?

Comment: Check out Google IO Session [here](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=wHAR46DT8ok), this should answer most of your question.

Comment: With 30 Request and a fill rate of 5% you have probably 2 Impressions. Since RPM refers to 1000 impressions you might need to get more impressions to see an increasing rpm.

Comment: @yorkw link is 404 now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AdMob works even if it's not published on the Market. Probably you're getting no money because nobody clicked on your banner; check in the report page on AdMob's site how many clicks you received. And keep in mind that most of the times a click is counted only if the advertiser page is fully loaded and that AdSense banners (if you've activated them) have a 48 hours delay.

Comment: yes I activate adSense banners, this means that after 48 I will receive something ? , where I can read more about this ?

Comment: Does leaving "Site URL:" with value "http://" will give me some money if someone click on the banner ? (cause my app is not published to the market)

Comment: From Google's email sent to publishers in April 2011: `All revenue and performance statistics from Google AdSense ads will be merged with AdMob ads in the Sites & Apps reporting section of your account.  Payment for Google AdSense ads will also be consolidated and issued as part of the AdMob payment process. Please note, daily reporting for Google AdSense ads may be delayed up to 48 hours.`

Comment: It doesn't matter it your app is published on the Android Market to receive money from AdMob; I only said that most of the times the click is counted only if the web page is fully loaded (AFAIK)

Comment: one more thing what is the difference with or without adSense activated ?

Comment: With AdSense you get a higher fill rate (when AdMob fails AdSens shows a banner), so it's easier to get money.

Comment: This is not the answer. You get paid even when nobody clicks your ad. You get paid for impressions.

Answer (score 5):

You can't expect money at 30 impressions. Self-clicks don't count and if you click more often, you will get banned. Maybe around 500 impressions the first money will come. Check that you enabled google ads for better fill rate-

Just wait and make another app. I hated the time until my apps became popular but I used it to make more apps. Now 2 of my apps are well-known and I can almost live from this money. Be creative.

Comment: give me your email, but about what you want to talk?

Comment: lbufsjob1@yahoo.com , we can about making money :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, simple answer: No one has clicked on the banner.
There may be 30 times that a banner has been requested (User opens the activity and admob tries to load a banner) but non of the Users has clicked on it.

Comment: well I clicked on it, I installed my app and I clicked the banner.

Comment: @Lukap clicking your own ads is a violation of the terms of service. don't do it

Comment: @uwe for apps, how does Google detects if _I clicked the banner_? I hope not just based on IP, else any one using the app on the same Wifi network will be considered as a single user, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

As it says in this picture, your Earnings will probably be (re)calculated at the end of the month after they have verified it.

[image: Admob Page Earning Desccription]